# Decoding halted because of invalid data in the stream

Tags: opc

I am using Workstation.UaClient 2.0
when i try to connect to
opc.tcp://My-PC:53530/OPCUA/SimulationServer
i am able to successfully connect to prosys OPC UA simulation server.
But when i try to create subscription,
In this line

```
BrowseResponse browseResponse = await channel.BrowseAsync(browseRequest);
```

it throw exception
**Decoding halted because of invalid data in the stream.**
Same code works with kepserver.
Please help to fix this issue.

Comment: Your version is outdated. Try to use the latest one (2.1.1) : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Workstation.UaClient/

Comment: @CamilleG You are correct. Version 2.1.1 is the answer.